# Is it possible to trigger a function upon a Vue data element change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My API provides me a hash which I receive as part of an AJAX call. The content of the AJAX response (which includes the hash) is updating `data` components in my `Vue` instance (so that the DOM is modified, per usual Vue usage).

I was wondering if it is possible to trigger (run) a function upon the change of a specific `data` element. [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) does not mention this and for me (please correct me if this is wrong)  `computed`and `methods` are a way to indirectly provide new computed elements for the DOM (in other words, they do not start because a specific element was modified but are rather synchronisation methods between `data` and other variables provided to the DOM).

I was hoping for something along the lines of (this is non-working, incorrect pseudo-code, I just add it to put in context of a Vue instance):

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
      hash: null
    },
    functions_to_trigger_upon_an_element_change: {
      hash: function () {
        location.reload()
      }
    }
  })
```

The idea above would be to have `location.reload()` run when the value of `hash` changes.

**Is there such a mechanism in Vue?**

If there is not, I will keep the state independently of Vue and act accordingly upon its change but it would be nice to reuse the Vue watch properties to do that.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use a watch, like the following example:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Foo',
    lastName: 'Bar',
    fullName: 'Foo Bar'
  },
  watch: {
    firstName: function (val) {
      this.fullName = val + ' ' + this.lastName
    },
    lastName: function (val) {
      this.fullName = this.firstName + ' ' + val
    }
  }
})
```

About your case, here is the example about how it could be implemented.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    hash: 'Foo' 
  },
  watch: {
    hash: function (val) {
      // when the hash prop changes, this function will be fired.
      location.reload()
    } 
  }
})
```

I hope I understood your question right.

Comment: How would I fire `location.reload()` upon the change of, say, `firstName` in your example?

Comment: The `hash` you have in your example, under `watch` is not related to the one under `data` (as far as I understand). It is a new variable (available via `data.hash` once it is created) and will probably overwrite the `data.hash` you set by default (to `'Foo'`). It is not that `hash` is "watched" and `function` is triggered once it changes -- which is exactly the functionality I am looking for (but `watch` does not provide it)

Comment: You were right, I was wrong. I just did a test in JSFiddle and it indeed works as you mentioned. Thank you very much. I will ask a separate question to exactly understand the mechanism of the getter().

Answer (score 5):

I think this should work

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
      hash: null
    },
    watch: {
        hash: function (val) {
          functions_to_trigger_upon_an_element_change()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        functions_to_trigger_upon_an_element_change() {
            // You code
        }
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the this. in the example above

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
      hash: null
    },
    watch: {
        hash: function (val) {
          this.functions_to_trigger_upon_an_element_change()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        functions_to_trigger_upon_an_element_change() {
            // You code
        }
    }
 })
```

Comment: Please provide a little explanation; code-only answers, even when correct, don't do much to help the OP figure out what they did wrong.